# Getting HTML code from Handlebars template on server-side

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

My NodeJS is supposed to send html email notifications from users. In order to keep the code clean, I would like to get the HTML code for those emails from handlebars templates, instead of hardcoding the HTML code into the sendEMail methods (which just looks plain ugly).

I need the server to get the HTML from those .handlebars files, but this is not working. Here is how I am trying to get the HTML code

```
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({});
var context = {
        title: 'T'
    }
var template = handlebars.render('../views/emails/passwordReset.handlebars', context);

console.log(template);
```

`Console.log(template)` is returning `{}`

Here is the .handlebars code:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
```

Can anyone provide guidance on what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1):

`handlebars.render` doesn't return the rendered text; rather, it returns a *promise*.  You can subscribe to the promise's success event to get the output:

```
handlebars.render('test.handlebars', context)
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I added the 'then' function but 'console.log(data)' never gets called in the debugger. Any ideas how?

Comment: Try also adding a `catch` handler to see if the promise isn't getting resolved.  Will update my answer demonstrating.